# How to allow wordpress site to display standalone HTML pages?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

This is my WP htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

I want wordpress' htaccess to stay out of the way when the link is to a standalone .html|.htm file inside the /ag directory.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/ag
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Doesn't work (I am aware the above code doesn't even try to implement the requirement that the file ends in .html|.htm). What do I need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original rewrite conditions only rewrite if the file does not exist, and is not a directory.

Therefore if you have the file in a directory, there should be no rewrite happening.

Comment: the original is the default wordpress htaccess and has nothing to do with my specific needs, as detailed in this question. with the original setup i get a wordpress-styled 404, even when the file i am requesting exists in the directory

Comment: if a file exists and your webserver can display it, it will. This rewrite rules say, if the file does not exist, call this php file(which just happens to be part of WordPress). And WordPress will then decide no such file is a related to WordPress and therefore show the WP 404.
Test this by remove the .htaccess file, and seeing what happens, when you try access your .html file.

Comment: What I'm saying is, what your asking for works out-of-the-box for a normal install. I don't think your problem is the .htaccess file, but something more server related.

Comment: Simeon's last comment nailed it. it turns out the file being requested had been deleted. the default rewrite rules do not need an exception when the file actually exists. thanks!

Comment: Glad to help. You're welcome to tick my post to mark it the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Wrong answers here. This thread helps:

[non-wordpress files in wordpress installation directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754548/non-wordpress-files-in-wordpress-installation-directory)

You need to specifically exclude the directory using rewrite rules, or Wordpress 3.4.1 won't allow access.